# How to make a borderContainer to listen for scroll events?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

There is my scenario:

I have a BorderContainer that is contained by a Scroller.

Question :

How can i make my BorderContainer to listen for Scroler events?

e.g. When i scroll down or up, or right or left, i want to change my BorderContainer's cordinates(x, y).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add an EventListener to the scroller and pass the event to the BorderContainer. An event bubbles upward and you want it downward, so you need to do it like I mentioned.